# Mysql Flush Host will it delete my data in tables...?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to connect to my DB on a server with Workbench, it took my a while to learn how to connect through workbench and in a process I blocked because of many connection errors.

I have learned through google and Mysql Documentation [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blocked-host.html) that i need to flash host to unblock the connection chanel

```
FLUSH HOSTS
```

I was trying to find out if that command will in any way affect data held in my DB, if it i will remove all the data in tables or remove users from table...?

Am I safe to run this command without emptying my tables...?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I believe so. Excerpt from [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/flush.html)

> HOSTS
>
> **Empties the host cache**. You should flush the host cache if some of
>   your hosts change IP address or if the error message Host 'host_name'
>   is blocked occurs. (See Section B.5.2.6, “Host 'host_name' is
>   blocked”.) When more than max_connect_errors errors occur successively
>   for a given host while connecting to the MySQL server, MySQL assumes
>   that something is wrong and blocks the host from further connection
>   requests. Flushing the host cache enables further connection attempts
>   from the host.

It clearly says that, it clears the host cache and not data stored in user/system database. So, running it should be fine/safe I believe.

Comment: can you provide me with the link to your source please :)

Comment: hehehe sorry my bad....Also if i flash hosts will I have to all the hosts again for connections or these will remain, just their catche is reseted..?

Comment: No, I believe you will have to reconnect.

Comment: @Tomazi, consider accepting the answer if it's helpful.